# Is there a way to unpack jars in runtime and access methods of classes?

Tags: java

This might be a little vague but I wanted to know if I have a class name (including the package) before hand, say in a file and I have a bunch of jars in the classpaths. Then is there a way I can look into a particular jar to find that class and access some method from that class?

What I am actually trying to do is to load some values from different class, dynamically. If the above approach is flawed then is there any other way to do it? Am not completely certain about how the class loader works, so I didn't want to go down that rabbit hole just yet.

**EDIT** An abstract example of what am trying to do:

I have a program that builds a graph for me using certain information, for the purpose of this example lets say that information is alphabets. I have some jars in my classpath that have a class that has a method that returns these alphabets for that specific class. Now I got the order of the classes I need to build the graph from, so if I am able to extract these alphabets from the jars, I can build my graph.

Comment: If the jars are on the classpath, then you shouldn't need to unpack them... what are you trying to do again? What different class are you trying to "load some values" from? What does that mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "access some method"? All you need is the name of the class and the method name and to use reflection. You don't need to "look in any particular jars", if it's on the classpath, it's accessible.

Comment: I have edit the question, but according to both your replies I think all I need to do is use reflection. Thank you!

Comment: @noMAD Something like [this](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/reflections.html)? (link is to my blog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [URLClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) and its methods to find classes in a .jar file (typically) once you have the Class object, you can use java.lang.reflect to instantiate objects, call methods, or inspect variables

Answer (score 0):

If the jars are your own: Consider using java.util.ServiceLoader. It helps to find any classes residing on the classpath at runtime that implement a given Interface, as long as you declare them in a META-INF/services list.
So you let the classloader load the classes without knowing their names and simply call their methods.

I'm not sure if there is a clean way to find out (enumerate) the names of all classes only by reflection without scanning the jars as a zip.