# Compare .java file to .class file

Tags: java, jar, .class-file

In my situation I have many `.jar` files being created from a build process. Before I do any debugging I want a way to quickly verify that my `.java` source matches the `.class` found in a `.jar`.

I figure that if I unzip the `.jar` and find the `.class` which matches my `.java` file then I should be able to determine if they're functionally the same.

How can I do this?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27024792/is-there-a-way-to-unpack-jars-in-runtime-and-access-methods-of-classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to realize is that compilation doesn't just use the specific .java file for the class being compiled. The compiler also uses information from the other .java and .class files available at compile time. For example, it may inline static final constants. Also, stuff like method overloading depends on which methods have been defined.

That being said, if you compile the same source file with the same compiler as before, you'll probably get the same, or a very similar class file. However, even with identical source files, different compilers (javac vs eclipse) and different versions of the compiler will produce different results.

Therefore, what I'd recommend is first try compiling everything and see if the classfiles match. If the class files don't match, try disassembling them with the Krakatau disassembler and do a diff on the diassemblies to see what the differences are. That will help you see if the difference is unimportant (such as a reordering of the constant pool) or if there are substantive changes to the bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a java decompiler like http://jd.benow.ca/ in order to be able to view the corresponding source of your class file then you will be able to compare it with your java file

Comment: This is probably the route I'm going to take. I was hoping for something automated, instead of having to visually verify.

Comment: @flkes sorry AFAIK there is no way to automate it even if you intended to automate the decompilation (which should be possible) because the result provided by the decompiler is not exactly what you have in your source code, for example you don't have any javadoc.

Comment: Maybe i can compile my .java file using the .jar as the classpath and compare the .class files?

Comment: Assuming that your jar doesn't have any dependencies and you use the exact same version of the JVM to compile, it could work indeed

Comment: @flkes: “*Maybe i can compile my .java file using the .jar as the classpath and compare the .class files?*” Maybe you should rethink your starting point. You wanted to ensure that the classes are up-to-date and now you’re going to recompile everything and *then* starting an attempt of comparing the results. Even if that comparison wasn’t error-prone, isn’t recompiling everything already enough to be sure that everything is up-to-date?

Comment: @Holger this was part of a larger build process that I didn't write myself. I only wanted to target my changes and also not have to read through all the ant descriptions to see if I actually used the right project name.

Comment: @flkes: this doesn’t change the fact that whatever you are going to compare this way is exactly what you have completely recompiled already.

Comment: @Holger nope. depending on the build target some files will just get repacked without re-compiling the source. So the jar will be new but not reflect every change since.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be enough for you if you can use a decompiler? Like one from IntelliJ IDE to see how is the source for you compiled class. You can even debug over the decompiled source.